# ImageView always return blank when set programmatically

Tags: android, android-bitmap

i still new to Android and want to know if there is a proper way to load image from an Input Stream.

If i load the image directly from Database the image will return the image just fine without any problem.
here my code to set ImageView Bitmap from Database :

```
varIDCardImageBinary = rs.getBinaryStream("IDCardImage");
classMyData.setDataInputStream(varIDCardImageBinary,"IDCardImage"); // Save Binary to a variable inside my Class
varimgIDCardView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(classMyData.getInputStream("IDCardImage")));
```

Code above is working fine, And as you can see. I actually call the image AFTER i save the image into a variable.

I also put the function if the variable in my class is not empty, the ImageView Bitmap will be set from the variable without needed to call from Database again. Here is my code to call the image :

```
varIDCardImageBinary = classMyData.getInputStream("IDCardImage");
varimgIDCardView.setImageResource(0);
varimgIDCardView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(varIDCardImageBinary));
```

And for some reason the ImageView is still BLANK, I have also tried code below to see if the Variable is empty or not :

```
Toast.makeText(DocumentAccountActivity.this, "Loaded From Class " + varIDCardImageBinary.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

But the result is not empty at all. Even so the ImageView still return blank. Is there anything wrong with how i set the Bitmap ? and What is the proper way to call it ?

EDITED :

I also have tried using Glide just like primo suggesting, but the result still the same.
here my code :

```
varIDCardImageBinary = classMyData.getInputStream("IDCardImage");
Glide.with(DocumentAccountActivity.this)
                .asBitmap().load(varIDCardImageBinary).into(varimgIDCardView);
```

Just in case you wondering, If i call the image from Database directly. it workes just fine. But i don't want my client to load all data from database every moment they open the activity.

Comment: See the answer in this link. This is an easy way to load image in imageview from database. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55219482/8101634

Comment: what is happened if you commenting `varimgIDCardView.setImageResource(0);`?

Comment: This is the way to call image in imageview not recyclerview. Glide is a library which makes it easy to load image in imageview

Comment: Yes i also have tried to commenting `varimgIDCardView.setImageResource(0);` , but the result still same.

Comment: @primo Tried your suggesting but result still same. But thanks for the suggestion

Comment: `varimgIDCardView.setImageResource(0);` just clear the image. It does not matter.

Comment: `varIDCardImageBinary.toString()`, `toString` method of a stream object returned non-null just means the java object `varIDCardImageBinary` is not null. What's the content of the string? If you use `Log.d()` instead of toast you can copy the string from logcat and paste here.

Comment: @MeowCat2012 here is the log : net.sourceforge.jtds.util.BlobBuffer$BlobInputStream@4a8942a0

Comment: So the log says the stream is not null. Depending on the implementation detail of your `classMyData` the actual bitmap may or may not be retrieved successfully.

Comment: @MeowCat2012 , thank you for the suggestion. But i also tried to Log.d the result of the image retrieved from the database, and Log.d the result of variable , and both is have EXACTLY same value. I also notice if i just save the retrieved image into variable without set the imageview. then reopen the activity and set image with the variable without retrieve from database, is Working without problem. but yet again if i re open the activity the image is blank again. Is ImageView can only be set once a time application running ?

Comment: No not once a time. With your `activity` closed, is there any other opened `activities` of your app? And what keep the variable `classMyData` alive with the `activity` closed, say, is it a **static** variable (called member field) of any `activity`?

Comment: Yes there is another activity. More detail is the activity to show the image is an activity when client click PROFILE BUTTON in main activity. so if there is another activity then yes, main activity is still active. and for how do i keep variable is i create a CLASS named classMyData with a static variable and simple function setData and getData. For your information. the data i retrieved from the class not only image but also TEXT and the text itself is success without any problem. But for the image for some reason still blank when set to ImageView.